# Regex to exclude previously captured characters

Tags: regex

How does the exclude operator ^ behave with previously captured values?

Notice the [^\1] in the regex below:

```
"abcdefgabcdefga".scan(/(\w)([^\1]+)(\1)/)
[
[0] [
    [0] "a",
    [1] "bcdefgabcdefg",
    [2] "a"
]
]
```

Notice the [^a] in the regex below:

```
"abcdefgabcdefga".scan(/(\w)([^a]+)(\1)/)

[
  [0] [
      [0] "a",
      [1] "bcdefg",
      [2] "a"
  ]
]
```

Seems the \1 and hardcoded 'a' are two different things?

I'm using ruby 2.1.1p76

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `\1` does represent back reference to `a` indeed but `[^\1]` is the problem here which is not same as `[^a]` since special meaning of `\1` gets lost inside character class.

Correct way of doing this is using negative lookahead like this:

```
(\w)(?:(?!\1).)+(\1)
```

#### [Ruby RegEx Demo](http://rubular.com/r/4iAvhhqnXi)

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said in other answers \1 is not a back reference when inside square brackets. 
The proposed solutions are viable, but just to throw out one more alternative that uses non-greedy matching:

```
/(\w)(.+?)(\1)/
```

That will stop as soon as it finds the back reference.